# OpenTelemetry Swift - make a single measurement

Tags: swift, metrics, open-telemetry

I'm new to OpenTelemetry and trying to implement it in an iPhone app.

I've tried sending traces, and it works fine - and the `CounterMetric.add(value: T, labels: [String: String])` also works!

However, I'm having problems with `MeasureMetric.record(value: T, labels: [String: String])`

I just called that method once, and then it kept on spamming endlessly.

Is this the intended behavior?

I just want to add a single measurement - can someone please help me do that? :-)